# Can't figure out why program is assigning one string to the whole array

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to create the 24 game in java to practice. The 24 Game is an arithmetical game in which the objective is to find a way to manipulate four integers so that the end result is 24. Addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division in any order of the numbers may be used to make the four digits operations from one to nine equal 24.

The rules are simple: you have to use each number only once and only the 4 numbers that were read from the user to find one equation to obtain 24.

My issue is my program is assigning the same equation to every element of the array. When it prints, I get "Found copy" and the same equation printed 20 times. The found copy is just a place holder right now. I would like the program to save new strings to the next element in the array and if it is a copy then to do nothing. I think I may have some incorrect logic in the loops in the `append` method. However, I can not figure it out.

```
public class TwentyFourGame {
    String [] ans = new String[20];
    boolean [] used = new boolean[ans.length];
    int count = 0;
    int value = 0;

    public void Solve(double w, double x, double y, double z){
        double [] nums = {w,x,y,z};
        double eHold=0, fHold=0;

        //Replaces null array elements with empty string to avoid NPE
        for(int d=0; d<ans.length;d++){
            ans[d] = "";
        }

        for (int a=0;a< 4; a++){
            for (int b=0;b< 3; b++){
                for (int c=0;c<2; c++){
                    fHold = nums[2]+nums[3];
                    if (((nums[0]/nums[1])*fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" / "+nums[1]+" * ("+nums[2]+" + "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]/nums[1])-fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" / "+nums[1]+" - ("+nums[2]+" + "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]*nums[1])-fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" * "+nums[1]+" - ("+nums[2]+" + "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]*nums[1])/fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" * "+nums[1]+" / ("+nums[2]+" + "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]-nums[1])*fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" - "+nums[1]+" * ("+nums[2]+" + "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]-nums[1])/fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" - "+nums[1]+" / ("+nums[2]+" + "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else value++;
                    fHold=nums[2]-nums[3];

                    if (((nums[0]/nums[1])*fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" / "+nums[1]+" * ("+nums[2]+" - "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]/nums[1])+fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" / "+nums[1]+" + ("+nums[2]+" - "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]*nums[1])+fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" * "+nums[1]+" + ("+nums[2]+" - "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]*nums[1])/fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" * "+nums[1]+" / ("+nums[2]+" - "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]+nums[1])*fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" + "+nums[1]+" * ("+nums[2]+" - "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]+nums[1])/fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" + "+nums[1]+" / ("+nums[2]+" - "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else value++;
                    fHold=nums[2]*nums[3];

                    if (((nums[0]/nums[1])-fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" / "+nums[1]+" * ("+nums[2]+" * "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]/nums[1])+fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" / "+nums[1]+" + ("+nums[2]+" * "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]-nums[1])+fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" - "+nums[1]+" + ("+nums[2]+" * "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]-nums[1])/fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" - "+nums[1]+" / ("+nums[2]+" * "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]+nums[1])-fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" + "+nums[1]+" - ("+nums[2]+" * "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]+nums[1])/fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" + "+nums[1]+" / ("+nums[2]+" * "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else value++;
                    fHold=nums[2]/nums[3];

                    if (((nums[0]-nums[1])*fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" - "+nums[1]+" * ("+nums[2]+" / "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]-nums[1])+fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" - "+nums[1]+" + ("+nums[2]+" / "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]*nums[1])+fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" * "+nums[1]+" + ("+nums[2]+" / "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]*nums[1])-fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" * "+nums[1]+" - ("+nums[2]+" / "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]+nums[1])*fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" + "+nums[1]+" * ("+nums[2]+" / "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]+nums[1])-fHold)==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" + "+nums[1]+" - ("+nums[2]+" / "+nums[3]+")" + " = 24");
                    else value++;
                    fHold=nums[1]*nums[2];

                    if (((nums[0]-fHold)/nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" - ("+nums[1]+" * "+nums[2]+") / "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]-fHold)+nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" - ("+nums[1]+" * "+nums[2]+") + "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]/fHold)+nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" / ("+nums[1]+" * "+nums[2]+") + "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]/fHold)-nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" / ("+nums[1]+" * "+nums[2]+") - "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]+fHold)/nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" + ("+nums[1]+" * "+nums[2]+") / "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]+fHold)-nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" + ("+nums[1]+" * "+nums[2]+") - "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else value++;
                    fHold=nums[1]-nums[2];

                    if (((nums[0]*fHold)/nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" * ("+nums[1]+" - "+nums[2]+") / "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]*fHold)+nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" * ("+nums[1]+" - "+nums[2]+") + "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]/fHold)+nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" / ("+nums[1]+" - "+nums[2]+") + "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]/fHold)*nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" / ("+nums[1]+" - "+nums[2]+") * "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else value++;
                    fHold=nums[1]/nums[2];

                    if (((nums[0]-fHold)*nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" - ("+nums[1]+" / "+nums[2]+") * "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]-fHold)+nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" - ("+nums[1]+" / "+nums[2]+") + "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]*fHold)+nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" * ("+nums[1]+" / "+nums[2]+") + "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]*fHold)-nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" * ("+nums[1]+" / "+nums[2]+") - "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]+fHold)*nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" + ("+nums[1]+" / "+nums[2]+") * "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]+fHold)-nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" + ("+nums[1]+" / "+nums[2]+") - "+nums[3] + " = 24"); 
                    else value++;
                    fHold=nums[1]+nums[2];

                    if (((nums[0]*fHold)/nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" * ("+nums[1]+" + "+nums[2]+") / "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]*fHold)-nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" * ("+nums[1]+" + "+nums[2]+") - "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]/fHold)-nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" / ("+nums[1]+" + "+nums[2]+") - "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else if (((nums[0]/fHold)*nums[3])==24)
                        append (nums[0]+" / ("+nums[1]+" + "+nums[2]+") * "+nums[3] + " = 24");
                    else value++;

                    if (value == 192){
                        append("There is no solution for this set of numbers");

                        this.count ++;
                    }
                    // 0=a 1=b 2=c 3=d
                    eHold=nums[2];
                    nums[2]=nums[3];
                    nums[3]=eHold;
                }
                eHold=nums[1];
                nums[1]=nums[2];
                nums[2]=nums[3];
                nums[3]=eHold;
            }
            eHold=nums[0];
            nums[0]=nums[1];
            nums[1]=nums[2];
            nums[2]=nums[3];
            nums[3]=eHold;
        }

        //Only prints elements with non-empty strings
        for (int j=0; j<ans.length;j++){
            if (ans[j] != "")
                System.out.println(ans[j]);
        }
    }


    //Method used to check if there are duplicates in the array of equations
    public void append(String equation){
        String text = equation;

        //Check if equation is a copy
        Copy:
        for (int c=0;c<ans.length;c++){
            if (text.equals(ans[c])){
                System.out.println("Found copy");
                break Copy;
            }

            //If it's not then add it to the array
            else {
                Add:
                for (int e=0;e<ans.length;e++){
                    if (used[e]==false){
                        ans[e] = text;
                        used[e] = true;
                        break Add;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[]args){
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 4 numbers between 1 - 9");
        double w,x,y,z;
        TwentyFourGame Player1 = new TwentyFourGame();
        w = input.nextDouble();
        x = input.nextDouble();
        y = input.nextDouble();
        z = input.nextDouble();
        input.close();
        Player1.Solve(w,x,y,z);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to preserve insertion order and you want a `Set`, why not use a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)?

Comment: You've got a triple loop in there, referenced by variables a, b, and c.  Do you use either of those variables in the loop?  If not, why not?

Comment: Did you try stepping through this with a debugger?